# Print Section of First Line from "ReadAllLine"

Tags: character

I am reading in a textfile into an array I have created called "input_pattern" as shown in the line below:

trainingpatterns.input_pattern = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Directory of textfile");

I am able to print the first line with the code:
Console.WriteLine(trainingpatterns.input_pattern[0]);

This prints : 1001001010101019

However I would like to just print the first four characters of the line(1001)

Anyone have any ideas how I could do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to read the first line and then print the `Substring` of that:

```
Console.WriteLine(input_pattern[0].Substring(0, 4));
```